# Mandate space if number has plus followed by anything but a 1 regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I've a regex code which validates phone number globally and it works fine. i came across a scenario where i need to add a condition to existing regex without breaking existing, which validates **if given number has plus(+) followed by anything but a 1** [test here](https://regex101.com/r/MxfJIN/1) .

**regex:**

```
^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$
```

I'm looking for more of (existing regex) && (new code)

**Sample data:**

+1123456789 valid

+1 123456789 valid

+91 7036022022 valid

+917036022022 invalid -> it needs space, so invalid

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i've added sample data.

Comment: why the first is valid no space?

Comment: its diffcult to read a regex, could you write in text all the rules ?  after if your regex works for all except your new rule, why not check if space exist with a simple if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your regex as follows:

```
^((\+(?=1|([^1].* ))\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5})?$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gt1JCq/1)

The main change is adding `(?=1|([^1].* ))` immediately after the first `\+`.

Explanation:
Adding a positive lookahead immediately after the `+` sign to look for conditions either

1. `+` followed immediately by a `1`, or (or with the `|`)
2. `+` NOT followed immediately by a `1` but need to be followed by a space somewhere after

Additional changes is replacing `{0,1}` located at the end to `?` to simplify the regex.

This should add new rule to your existing regex without affecting its existing rules.

Comment: excellent! appreciate your in detail comments.

Comment: Note that using [^1] here is possible without matching non-digits because your other regex rules (i.e. \d{1,3} has already ensure what's following the `+` sign are digits.  On the other hand, this make the rule simple to understand.

Comment: yes i understood that. ^1 is perfect as my other rules takes care as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^(?!\+[02-9]\S*$)(?:\+\d{1,3}[- ]?\(?\d\)?[- ]?\d{1,5}|\(?\d{2,6}\)?)[- ]?\d{3,4}[- ]?\d{4}(?: (?:x|ext)\d{1,5})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEMZ0j/2).

The pattern is basically the same, I remove extra capturing groups and replaced `(-| )` with `[- ]` character class. The main point here is the `(?!\+[02-9]\S*$)` lookahead. It is a negative lookahead that fails the match if the string starts with `+`, then has a digit other than `1` and then any zero or more chars other than whitespace till the end of string.